# Is there any faster way to do bulk AS in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, syntax, ssms, shortcut

just wondering is there any shortcut to do this?

```
SELECT  CustomerID AS 'Customer ID',
        CustomerName AS 'Customer Name',
        CustomerAddress AS 'Customer Address',
        CustomerDOB AS 'Date of Birth',
        CustomerUsername AS 'Username',
        CustomerPassword AS 'Password'
FROM Customer
```

So I don't have to type in the whole `CustomerID`, `CustomerName` and so on?
Sorry for asking such question, I am a complete beginner and curiousity got me this time

Comment: `select c1,c2, c3 from (select col1, col2, col3 from tablename) as t (c1,c2,c3)`. However, I'd recommend sticking to your current way.

Comment: How is the database supposed to know the names you want to apply?  Your question just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Yeah, I know it's kinda stupid to ask such thing, but I was looking for a way to shorten them, similar to @jarlh mentioned above. Seems like there is no shortcut to do this, ah well. Thanks for the answers mate

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I'm using SQL Server (SSMS), will update it